# Why is Harish-Chandra's last name never used?

Tags: math-history, mathematicians

This is only barely a math question but I don't know where else to ask. I've always wondered about Harish-Chandra's name. The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra) seems to mention "Mehrotra" as a last name but only in passing, and it's not even used in the page's title. Did he simply not use a last name?

Comment: Are you sure you have the name order in his native language right? It might be a last-name-first language.

Comment: I don't think it's last-first in any of the ethnic groups I'm familiar with in India, and I also think "Mehrotra" is a pretty common *last* name. But of course that's a perfectly fine answer if that's the case, that Harish-Chandra *is* the last name, although it's still odd that the first name is always absent, even from the Wiki article's title.

Comment: Name order is right. Although it is not characteristic of all (Hindi) speakers, it was a tradition in northern states to officially refer by first names, titles, occupation, then last name (which encoded socio-cultural information and hence was generally omitted in professional contexts). I am not a historian but this is a general guess from my familiarity with that region.

Comment: @Approximist - this is interesting, thanks. Do you have examples of other public figures whose last name was omitted in professional contexts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in *I have a photographic memory* Halmos mentions in the brief description under H.-C.'s picture that Harish-Chandra insisted that this was his full name, no first name, no last name. I can't check it at the moment.

Comment: **Correction:** The passage I mentioned in my previous comment reads 'Harish (who denied having a "first name" in the usual American sense) ...', so I had misremembered. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Theo Buehler, that's a good catch!

Comment: While reading [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1991-16015-5) (on the recommendation of Matt E) I stumbled over the pointer to Langlands's extensive [biography of Harish-Chandra](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsbm.1985.0008). While both texts don't seem to answer your question, you might still be interested in having a look at them.

Comment: @Theo, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A link to a [biography](http://www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/harish-chandra.pdf) by Roger Howe now shows up on Wikipedia, and it has this to say:

> about the name harish-chandra: indian names do not  necessarily follow
>   the western two-part pattern of given name,  family name. a person may
>   often have only one name, and  this was the case with harish-chandra,
>   who in his youth was  called  harishchandra.  the hyphen was bestowed
>   on him  by the copy editor of his first scientific papers, and he kept
>   it.  later he adopted “chandra” as a family name for his  daughters.
>   given names in india are often those of gods or  ancient heroes, and
>   “harishchandra” was a king, legendary  for his truthfulness already at
>   the time of the mahabharata.  i once saw an indian comic book whose cover featured
>   “harishchandra—whose name is synonymous with truth.”

Answer (score 0):

During the independence movement, Harish-Chandra's father under the influence of Mahatma Gandhi decided to do away with using the caste name 'Mehrotra' as also started using Khadi attire. As for the hyphen it was a mistake by a sub-editor publishing his first paper but Harishchandra decided to retain it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Do you have a source for that assertion concerning Harish-Chandra's father?